# Elasticsearch: why Java client uses different query syntax?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. I have the following query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "term" : {
                    "title" : "crime"
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { "year" : 1961 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It runs fine under Windows prompt as follows:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/book/_search?pretty -d @my-query.json
```

For the same query with Java client, I have the following:

```
    SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch("book")
            .setTypes("fiction")
            .setQuery(query_string)
            .setFrom(page)
            .setSize(10).execute().actionGet();
```

However, I have to the following query string in order to run it without exception:

```
{

        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "term" : {
                    "title" : "crime"
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { "year" : 1961 }
            }
        }

}
```

Why is there such a difference? How can I retain the removed "query" property"? Suppose that I have to use query string in my Java client.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the two variants you show are not the same: you don't specify the type, offset, or size parameters in your URI-based query (even though you can do it there too, according to the [docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html)). You can omit these parameters in Java query as well:

```
SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch("book")
            .setQuery(query_string)
            .execute().actionGet();
```

Regarding the argument for setQuery, it can be either the same JSON as you have in your URI variant:

```
String theQuery = String.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"),
   "{\"filtered\" : {\"query\" : {\"term\" : {\"title\" : \"crime\"}},",
    "\"filter\" : {\"term\" : { \"year\" : 1961 }}}}");

SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch("book") 
.setTypes("fiction")
.setFrom(page)
.setQuery(queryString(theQuery)).execute().actionGet();
```

Or you can provide the analog of this query using Java methods:

```
SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch("book") 
.setTypes("fiction")
.setFrom(page)
.setQuery(filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("title","crime"),
                       FilterBuilders.termFilter("year","1961")))
.execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Ashalynd, thanks so much for helping me! Where did you get String.join method? theQuery variable you use contains is NOT the same query string as what I used in Windows prompt. Can I use exactly the same query string as in Windows prompt in Java client? Why do I have to remove "query" as shown (which is also shown in your theQuery)?

Comment: the outer "query" is designating a query part, it's not needed because the method is already called setQuery.

Comment: Regarding String.join: it's Java8. If you can't use it, you can look at StringUtils from Apache where there is a similar functionality, or guava library.